# Running a script from execl()

Tags: c, exec

I want to use `execl()` to start a script that has no execution rights. When done from the commandline, this works fine:

```
[bf@bf-laptop-tbwb playground]$ /bin/sh test.sh
I run !
```

However, when I want to use `execl` from C, it just starts another shell, without running my script.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  execl("/bin/sh", "/home/bf/playground/test.sh", NULL);    
  return 0;
}
```

I cannot just run the script, because I have no guarantee the script is executable (it is on an embedded device, that gets loaded with FTP scripts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "/home/bf/playground/test.sh", (char *) NULL);
/* exec*()-functions do not return on success, so we only get here in case of error. */
perror("execl() failed");
```

From [`man 3 exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

> The initial argument for these functions is the name of a file that
>          is to be executed.
>
> The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the **execl()**, **execlp()**,
>          and **execle()** functions can be thought of as *arg0, arg1, ..., argn*.

`arg0` is equivalent to `arg[0]` which is the program's name. The 1<sup>st</sup> argument to a program is `arg[1]`.

---

Also please note (further down of [`exec*()`'s man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)):

> The list of
>          arguments must be terminated by a null pointer, and, since these are
>          variadic functions, this pointer must be cast *(char *) NULL*.