# How to redirect output of a spawned child process in Linux?

Tags: linux, exec

```
     pid_t pid;
     pid=fork();
     if (pid == 0)
     {
         //child process.
         execl("/opt/bin/version.out", "version.out > /tmp/version",0);
         _exit(0);
     }
     else
     {
         // this is parent, wait for child to finish.
         waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
         verDir("/tmp/version");
     }
```

With the above c++ code, I am trying to create a child process, execute command  /opt/bin/version.out and redirect the output to /tmp/version, but it doesn't create  /tmp/version at all, any error with above syntax? is execl() and waitpid() syntax correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '>' redirection is not valid in execl as it is a shell command....

Try to look at [Running a script from execl()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250718/running-a-script-from-execl) for an example of how to invoke a shell to do your execution....

If you want to avoid the shell invokation, you will have to do a 'dup' call to close the stderr/stdout in the chiled process and open it to the file -- you can see an example here;
[fork, pipe exec and dub2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283329/fork-pipe-exec-and-dub2)

Or in your child process, you can force the output to a specific file, by closing the stdout and reopen it as the file, like this;

```
 if (pid == 0)
     {
         //child process.
         close(1);
         creat("/tmp/version",0644); // this will create a new stdout
         close(2);
         dup(1);   // this will make stderr to also go to the same file.....

         execl("/opt/bin/version.out", "version.out",0);
         perror("execl didn't work"); // print out the error if execl failed...
         _exit(0);
     }.....
```

Comment: Thanks Soren, have few questions: I don't want stderr to go into /tmp/version, so do I still need dup(1) ? and what does close(2) do ?  _exit(0) will always exit with return value 0? I want to check the status in parent, so don't want to return 0 all the time.

Comment: If you dont want stderr to go to the same file, then you either leave out the close(2);dup(1); or you make it go to a different file, using creat(...) instead of dup, or make it go to /dev/null by using a sequence of close(2); open("/dev/null",1);

Comment: How do I revert this to get the stdout back on screen?

Answer (score 1):

Redirection is a shell function, not a kernel function. You could run your command through the shell:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "/opt/bin/version.out > /tmp/version", (char *)NULL);
```

As an easier alternative, you could use `popen()` to run `/opt/bin/version.out` and read its output directly into your program. You would not have to use `/tmp/version` in this case.

```
FILE *version = popen("/opt/bin/version.out", "r");
... read from version ...
pclose(version);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the redirection in the argument of **execl** (which is incorrect), it should be done as part of a **dup2** call.

Here is a code snippet on how to redirect to a a file instead of stdout without any error checking.

```
 int fd = open ("/tmp/version", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC); 
 dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO); 
 close(fd);
```

Now, you can launch your binary using **execl**

```
 execl("/opt/bin/version.out","version.out", (char*)0);
```

Do please add appropriate error checking for existence of a file and access permissions.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to run it in a shell:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "/opt/bin/version.out > /tmp/version", (char*)NULL);
```

You should also be checking the return value of execl for errors.